# How to properly insert new row in correct specific row cell in the table view (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so here is my question..

i was trying to insert a row in some index with add button inside that row..

example : i click add button at row 1, then it should add new row below that row, if i click add button at row 3 it should add new row below it..

the problem is after i add example 5 new row, then sometimes if i click add in row 5 (this is new row added with new add button to inside it) it keep adding below last row that clicked.. (i click add on row 3 then it has new row below it, then i click add on the new row it keep adding below row 3)

Steps in my GIF :

1. I add new first row it adding new row below it.. (correct behavior)
2. I try add new row in last row but keep adding new row below row 3.
       (wrong behavior)
3. I try click again add row in row 4 it correctly add
       new row below it, and click on row 3 , it add correctly new row
       below it. (correct behavior)

Why i keep get problem in number 2 ?

Here is my code :

the problem is in case ingredient and step.. i already give rowId in the cell using indexPath so each cell has their own id.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.section]
        switch item.type {
        case .title:
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopUpTitleCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopUpTitleCell {
                return cell
            }
        case .category:
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopUpCategoryCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopUpCategoryCell {
                return cell
            }
        case .ingredient:
            if let item = item as? PopUpModelIngredient, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopUpIngredientStepCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopUpIngredientStepCell {
                cell.cellId = indexPath.row
                cell.item = item
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        case .step:
            if let item = item as? PopUpModelStep, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopUpIngredientStepCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopUpIngredientStepCell {
                cell.cellId = indexPath.row
                cell.item = item
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        case .post:
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopUpPostCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopUpPostCell {
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

this one is the delegate handler that i create to pass which cell that click the add button

```
func addedNewCell(inSection: Int, cellId: Int) {
        popUpTableView?.beginUpdates()
        let item = items[inSection]
        if let item = item as? PopUpModelIngredient {
            item.ingredientsCell += 1
            popUpTableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: cellId, section: inSection)], with: .automatic)
        }else if let item = item as? PopUpModelStep {
            item.stepsCell += 1
            popUpTableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: cellId, section: inSection)], with: .automatic)
        }
        popUpTableView?.endUpdates()
        print("added in section \(inSection) and cell id \(cellId)")
    }
```

the last one is the cell itself

```
class PopUpIngredientStepCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellId: Int?

    var delegate: CellAddedDelegate?

    var item: PopUpViewModelItem?

    static var nib:UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    @IBAction func addMoreCell(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Cell id for this one is : ", cellId)
        if item?.type == .ingredient {
            delegate?.addedNewCell(inSection: 2, cellId: cellId! + 1)
        }else{
            delegate?.addedNewCell(inSection: 3, cellId: cellId! + 1)
        }

    }


}
```

Here is the GIF and the number of the step information..

[GIF Link](http://gph.is/2v3Ao9N)

or the real low quality gif here

[image]

Comment: Your code is correct, there is no issue with that. The GIF that you have added, it is not clear which cell has been clicked but I tried your code in a sample project and it is working fine.

Comment: @Amit : Yes it works fine, it can added a row.. actually i put step on the gif (number and it is reflecting what i wrote in the steps section)
so after i click add on first row 4 times it will add 4 new row, but then if u click the second last new row, it will add below first row not below second last row , thats my problem... are u getting this one too ?

Comment: It is working fine on my side. Except I did one change. I haven't used "cellId". Instead of that I am setting tag value to add button and using the tag value as sender.tag in addMoreCell method.

Comment: @Amit interesting.. the tag value what did u fill it ?  did u fill it with indexpath.row as well ? and instead of sent back the cellId u sent a sender.tag for second parameter ?

Comment: Yes the tag value is indexpath.row and sender.tag + 1 as second parameter.